# Why is this "side" singular?

Tags: nouns, plural-forms

> They [Percy’s twin younger brothers] frog-marched Percy from the room,
>   his arms pinned to his **side** by his sweater.
>
> (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

They pinned Percy’s ‘two’ arms. But why isn’t the ‘side’ plural form?

Comment: Perhaps JKR is acknowledging that Percy is a pretty one-dimensional character?

Comment: @StoneyB, even if I confirmed the typo(?), your this comment is very probable. I checked how Jima Dale reads this: he does "side." Percy's arms might be tucked into a sleeve, and it may has the literature meaning as you observed.

Comment: I think if JKR had meant us to understand that two arms were forced into one sleeve she would have told us: she enjoys that sort of silliness (as I do, too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be an error introduced when the text was modified for the US edition. In the original UK edition it reads:

> ‘I – don’t – want –’ said Percy thickly, as the twins forced the
>   jumper over his head, knocking his glasses askew.
>    ‘And you’re not sitting with the Prefects today, either,’ said
>   George. ‘Christmas is a time for family.’
>    They frog-marched Percy from the room, his arms pinned to his
>   **sides** by his jumper.

Note that ‘jumper’ has been changed to ‘sweater’, to conform to US usage.